# Selenium cant find elements on page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have homework to make a program in python with Selenium to send an email on hotmail. Everything was working fine till I had to find the "New Message" button (or any other button on that page to be honest)
Im constantly getting `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:`

- I tried By : `Class,Xpath,FullXpath,Css Selector`. Can't find the name or Id
  using the inspector.
- I tried to make it wait with `time.sleep`

I really don't know what to do.
My code is here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\SeleniumDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://login.live.com/")
searchField = driver.find_element_by_name("loginfmt")
searchField.send_keys("")
nextButton = driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()
passfield = driver.find_element_by_id("i0118")
passfield.send_keys("")
time.sleep(1)
signInButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='idSIButton9']").click()
time.sleep(2)
try:
    nobutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='idBtn_Back']").click()
finally:
    time.sleep(2)
appbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='O365_MainLink_NavMenu']").click()
time.sleep(10)
outlookbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='O365_AppTile_Mail']").click()
time.sleep(15)
newmessageButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/span/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]").click()
time.sleep(6)
```

Requested HTML:

```
<div class="XayzgKk2Ga7sG02AhkQKJ"><div class="_1qPqjoFrRhZTOpwH-IJ2UP"><button type="button" class="ms-Button ms-Button--icon is-checked _3YkNJYKjMvYWaDLQ_t6D9- root-157" title="Toggle Left Pane" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle Left Pane" data-is-focusable="true"><span class="ms-Button-flexContainer flexContainer-158" data-automationid="splitbuttonprimary"><i data-icon-name="GlobalNavButton" aria-hidden="true" class="ms-Button-icon icon-167"></i></span></button></div><div class="_2nxYvsT9VmpG24V7lwcfcu"><div class=""><div class=""><button type="button" class="ms-Button GJoz3Svb7GjPbATIMTlpL _2W_XxC_p1PufyiP8wuAvwF lZNvAQjEfdlNWkGGuJb7d ms-Button--commandBar Gf6FgM99ZJ9S8H48pFMdB _3o6O4cjBEmQ4Q19oQJZZiF root-168" data-is-focusable="true"><span class="ms-Button-flexContainer flexContainer-158" data-automationid="splitbuttonprimary"><i data-icon-name="ComposeRegular" aria-hidden="true" class="ms-Button-icon _1y8YJ1XNBkLjckwryuEz2e icon-172"><span role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" class="w_jrWE2b2u-icz2udikRM"><svg class="_9fiU2J67uJPVP0DBdOFMW" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M14.85 1.85a.5.5 0 10-.7-.7l-8 8L6 10l.85-.15 8-8z"></path><path d="M4.5 2A2.5 2.5 0 002 4.5v7A2.5 2.5 0 004.5 14h7a2.5 2.5 0 002.5-2.5v-5a.5.5 0 00-1 0v5c0 .83-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5h-7A1.5 1.5 0 013 11.5v-7C3 3.67 3.67 3 4.5 3h5a.5.5 0 000-1h-5z"></path></svg></span></i><span class="ms-Button-textContainer textContainer-159"><span class="ms-Button-label uHWG8PYRNYDO2895_TmUG label-170" id="id__6">New message</span></span></span></button></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: if you can not find it using the inspector in dev-tools, selenium will also not be able to find it. You have to first find it there. If you need help with that you will have to post at least also some html.

Comment: I tried all xpaths conncted to the button. This is only the last one.

Comment: @Chai I posted HTML of button and anything releated to it.

Answer (score 0):

The "New message" button would be this selector in xpath:

`"//button[contains(., 'New message')]"`

Also, you might have an easier time choosing the correct selector if you use a record/playback/export tool to generate a script for you. Since you're already using Python, I recommend the SeleniumBase Recorder: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/recorder_mode.md (It should help you generate a full script with selectors more easily.)

Comment: "//button[contains(., 'New message')]" is not working (same msg). I am watching video on SeleniumBase Recorder. I am still new with python and Selenium so never heard of that till now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, once you click on outlook on first windows a new tab is opened and there we have a new message button. So in order to click on that, you would have to make sure that Selenium is switching to the new tab.

```
first_win_handle = driver.current_window_handle
outlookbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='O365_AppTile_Mail']")
outlookbutton.click()

all_win_handles = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(all_win_handles[1])

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='New message']/ancestor::button"))).click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the element by id, but the element does not have an id. So that does not work.
You will either have to ensure the element gets that correct id, or use a different way to locate it.

You might try finding it by Css Selector:
`'button[data-automationid="splitbuttonprimary"]'`

Make sure to use the right quotes. Try this in the inspector first and you should find it. If you do not: it will not work, no matter the code.
If you see multiple hits then the css is not specific enough, and you will need to find a more specific way to locate it.

That selector basically means: an `element` of type "button" with `attribute` "data-automationid" with value "splitbuttonprimary". You can read more about locating specicif elements, css selectors, html elements and attributes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)